# How can I identify / tag MySQL queries so that I can find them in my application quickly?

Tags: mysql, sql, tags

I'm using the slow query log and sometimes the general log to debug problems, but so many of my queries are written similarly in my application that I don't know where in the application it is. Is there a way to append something to each query so that I can use it for identification?

For example add a tag like "lookingforuserswithreferrals" in the query (which doesn't actually do anything), and then find that keyword in my application?

Comment: maybe just a comment? something like: 
-- queryId: xy

Comment: Yeah only thought of it after posting this :)